# How can I publish WAR file

Tags: tomcat, hosting, war

I'm have a WAR file export from eclipse, now i want to deploy into server tomcat running on linux server hosting, but i can't set up to run this project ?
I'm using RICHFACES 4, Tomcat 6
I've already copy WAR file to folder webapps but server didn't deploy WAR file.
Thanks for helping and sorry about my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using a 3rd party hosting. You need to read their developer documentation / user guide how to deploy web applications to it. On most (usually the elcheapo ones), you need to extract the WAR yourself and then upload the WAR's contents to the "public" www folder yourself. A WAR file is basically a ZIP file, so you should be able to extract it yourself with any ZIP tool.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop Tomcat.
2. Delete existing deployment. If you have previously deployed "foo.war" in TOMCAT_HOME/webapps, then it has been unpacked into webapps/foo/... You must delete this directory and all its contents. On Unix, this can be done with
     rm -r $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/foo
3. Copy WAR file to TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/.
4. Start Tomcat.

For more details Check http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=123229

Comment: Thanks for answer but it's not working
My hosting have 2 folder : tomcat and www
I uploaded to folder tomcat/webapps and start up tomcat but it's not deploy WAR file.
When i create a.jsp file in folder www and run with link www.mypage.com/a.jsp , it's working 
So , how can i call WAR file in folder tomcat when i standing in folder www . 
Thanks you very much